# Is std::stringstream::flush() supposed to do anything?

Tags: c++, stringstream, std, streambuf

`std::ostream`'s have a [`flush()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) method which:

> Writes uncommitted changes to the underlying output sequence.

What does that mean for an `std::stringstream`? If I understand correctly, it means there's nothing to be done for such a stream. Is this true?

Answer (score 6):

`flush()` triggers a call of the stream's `rdbuf` member's [`pubsync()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsync) method (which in turn calls `sync()` ). For string streams, the `rdbuf` is a `std::basic_stringbuf`, and as the link indicates, its `pubsync()`/`sync()` behavior is to do nothing.

Thus, indeed, your assumption is valid: **`std::stringstream::flush()` does nothing.**

Comment: Indeed, maybe interesting to mention that this method exists to ensure that you can use any kind of stream without knowing it's implementation

Comment: @JVApen: I think people know about being able to `<< std::flush` to every ostream; but fair enough.